# How to query emails logged via Einstein Activity Capture?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

We have some users set up with Einstein Activity Capture/Salesforce Inbox (this was before my time and I don't have much experience with EAC).

These emails do not display all recipients in the Activity feed, only 1 recipent followed by "+ *x* others".

I cannot find these emails via a SOQL from Task or EmailMessage (in contrast, emails logged via the Outlook Add-in for Salesforce can be queried using both objects). I also couldn't find these emails in a Salesforce report (Activities with Accounts & Activities with Contacts).

I found this [idea on the IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZD1UAN/view-all-recipients-of-an-email-when-using-einstein-activity-capture) which makes me think this is missing functionality.

Does anyone with EAC experience have ways to find the recipient information for EAC emails in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

"Because activities added to Salesforce with Einstein Activity Capture aren’t stored in Salesforce, they don’t show up in standard Salesforce reports. However, Einstein Activity Capture provides access to the Activities dashboard, which shows a summary of sales activities that were added to Salesforce manually and by Einstein Activity Capture. You can also use Activity Metrics to get a complete picture of your activities."

Here we need to change the solution because of this limitation.

However if you need to share these meetings with a group of users.
You need to create a public calendar here https://[YOUR_DOMAIN].lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/Calendars/home and put roles, public groups, etc...

If the emails couldn't shared this way. Try to create a public group in chatter.